# How to create a new ALAsset from downloaded image

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, alassetslibrary

I am trying to develop an application which would download images (from a photography site) and create a ALAsset for each image and then place them under a new ALAssetsGroup.

I am able to create a new Album (ALAssetsGroup) and download data from the website. However i am a bit stuck on how to create the new ALAsset.

I have tried is as follows

```
            ALAsset *asset = [[[ALAsset alloc] init] autorelease];
            NSDictionary *metadata = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:p.id, @"id", p.thumbnail_url, @"thumbnail_url", p.photo_url, @"photo_url", nil];
            [asset setImageData:data metadata:metadata completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
                ESLog(@"Asset %@ created error:%@", assetURL, error);
                [group addAsset:asset];
            }];
```

However I get prints where both the assetURL and error is empty.

```
2012-04-15 02:58:06.850 XXXXXX.com[5966:c607] Asset (null) created error:(null)
```

It would be great if someone can suggest how i can create a new Asset in an Album

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you cant create a new ALAsset like that.
What you need to do is save you image data to the Photo-Library using the method:

```
- (void)writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:(NSData *)imageData metadata:(NSDictionary *)metadata completionBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryWriteImageCompletionBlock)completionBlock
```

The completion block will return the NSURL for the new created asset. Using the method

```
- (void)assetForURL:(NSURL *)assetURL resultBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock)resultBlock failureBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock)failureBlock
```

with the NSURL will return you the ALAsset instance of the newly created asset.

Cheers.

Hendrik

Comment: Thanks, that is how i ended up doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` function to save the `UIImage` to the camera's rollover.

```
void UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum (
   UIImage  *image,
   id       completionTarget,
   SEL      completionSelector,
   void     *contextInfo
);
```

It is described [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html).

Then you can pick it up from the Asset library.

Answer (score 1):

Even easier use the following code :

```
    //Save to photo album
    UIImage *img = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData] autorelease];
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:img.CGImage
                                 metadata:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata]
                          completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
                              NSLog(@"assetURL %@", assetURL);
                          }];
```