# ALAsset not editable

Tags: objective-c, ios, alasset

For some reason the editable property for an ALAsset object is always set to false in the following code:

```
ALAsset *testAsset = [[ALAsset alloc] init];

if(!testAsset.editable)
{
    NSLog(@"This always prints.");
}
```

I'm trying to set image data to this asset and then save it to an asset group, but can't because it's not editable.  Apple documentation says I can only edit ALAsset objects that I create myself, which I'm doing in the code above.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently my method above of creating a new ALAsset object is not the way to do it:
[How to create a new ALAsset from downloaded image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157538/how-to-create-a-new-alasset-from-downloaded-image)

That post says it's necessary to save the image first before obtaining the ALAsset.  I'll plan on doing that and then adding the asset to my custom asset group (album).